# Exclude Apex trigger functionality for one record type of object

Tags: apex, trigger, record-type

We have Trigger on Custom object(Appointment). We have different record types for that object and we don't want the functionality to one of it. Hence i am trying to add if condition inside the trigger comparing RecordTypeID.(  if(appointmentsReference.RecordTypeId!='012b0000000M8ry')) It is throwing error. Variable doesn't exist

```
trigger AppointmentTrigger on Appointment__c (before insert, before update, after delete, after insert, after update) {


    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if(Trigger.IsInsert){            


            new ConfidentialityManagement(Trigger.new,null).assignOnInsert('Account__c','Master_Account__c');
        }else if(trigger.isUpdate){
            new ConfidentialityManagement(Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap).assignOnUpdate('Account__c','Master_Account__c');
        }

    } 

    else if (Trigger.isAfter) {

        Appointments appointmentsReference = new Appointments(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
        else if (Trigger.isAfter) {

            Appointments appointmentsReference = new Appointments(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
            if(appointmentsReference.RecordTypeId!='012b0000000M8ry')
            {
                if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                    AccountAssetsTeamManager.assignAssetTeamMembers(Trigger.new); /*  CD 7 | 10/6/2013 || Changed to generalize code | 24/3/2015 */
                    appointmentsReference.insertEvents(); /* CD 2 | Ewa Byra (ewa.byra@outbox.pl) | 4/6/2013 */
                } else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
                    AccountAssetsTeamManager.changeAssetShares(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap); /*  CD 7 | 10/6/2013 || Changed to generalize code | 24/3/2015 */
                    appointmentsReference.updateEvents(); /* CD 2 | Ewa Byra (ewa.byra@outbox.pl) | 4/6/2013 */
                } else if (Trigger.isDelete) {
                    appointmentsReference.deleteEvents(); /* CD 2 | Ewa Byra (ewa.byra@outbox.pl) | 4/6/2013 */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your Appointments class is not having a RecordTypeId attribute. You need to ask a specific record for its record type Id. Or expose it via your wrapper class.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? What variable doesn't exist? Even if you resolve that error you declare `Appointments appointmentsReference` twice (and also `else if (trigger.isAfter)`...)

Comment: In this line   if(appointmentsReference .RecordTypeId!='012b0000000M8ry')  Where i am trying to compare RecordType Id which i am excluding to run this logic.

Comment: -@Basti It has I can even query the name RecordType id by using query editor

Comment: If `Appointment` is a custom object shouldn't you need to append `__c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a Variable first for a Record Type.

```
id Recordtype =Schema.SObjectType.Appointment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Your Record type Name').getRecordTypeId();
```

and then in If condition.

```
if(appointmentsReference.RecordTypeid!=Recordtype)
 {
    // enter your code
 }
```